# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how do I follow a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a link on my page that will take you to 2 different places 
if its the first time that you press that link it will take you to the new action all other times will take to the update but the both links have the same text.

```
When /^I follow "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  ???
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o.k same text for the link:

```
When /^I follow "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
      click_link "Follow"
end

Then /^he should see hello message$/ do
  page.should have_selector('div.hello')
end
```

Comment: in his case it is a link! Thx for your help.